# PHP Reuse a MySQL object in function outside of the class

Tags: php, mysql, class

I usee this class below to connect to my sql db. Everything is fine, but I think I'm not using it in the proper way. When a page is loaded on my website, some functions are called to display text, sponsors... and each function creates an mysql object. Is it wrong?? Can it create a too many connections issue? Should I create one object and pass it a a param for the functions?? or is there a way to make this object global?

```
class clsMysql
{
    var $con;
    var $last_id;

    function __construct($db = array()) 
    {
        $this->con = mysql_connect($db['host'], $db['user'], $db['pass'], true, MYSQL_CLIENT_INTERACTIVE) or die ('Error connecting to MySQL');
        mysql_select_db($db['db'], $this->con) or die('Database ' . $db['db'] . ' does not exist!');
    }

    function __destruct() {
        mysql_close($this->con);
    }

    // fonction qui exécute la requête SQL
    function fxQuery($sql) {
        return mysql_query($sql, $this->con);
    }

    // fonction qui retourne la variable du résultat de la requête SQL
    function fxGetVar($sql) {
        return $this->fxFetchArray(0, $sql);
    }

    // fonction qui retourne un tableau contenant la ligne unique du résultat de la requête SQL
    function fxGetRow($sql) {
        return $this->fxFetchArray(1, $sql);
    }

    // fonction qui retourne un tableau contenant le résultat de la requête SQL
    function fxGetResults($sql) {
        return $this->fxFetchArray(2, $sql);
    }

    // fonction qui met la requête dans un tableau
    function fxFetchArray($p, $sql)
    {
        $qry = $this->fxQuery($sql);
        $nb = mysql_num_rows($qry);
        $this->last_id = mysql_insert_id($this->con);

        if ($nb > 0)
        {
            switch ($p)
            {
                // fxGetVar
                case 0:
                    $rec = mysql_fetch_array($qry, MYSQL_NUM);
                    $mem_results = $rec[0];
                    break;

                // fxGetRow
                case 1:
                    $rec = mysql_fetch_array($qry, MYSQL_ASSOC);

                    foreach (array_keys($rec) as $field)
                        $mem_results[$field] = $rec[$field];
                    break;

                // fxGetResults
                case 2:
                    $ctr = 1;

                    while ($rec = mysql_fetch_array($qry, MYSQL_ASSOC))
                    {
                        foreach (array_keys($rec) as $field)
                            $mem_results[$ctr][$field] = $rec[$field];

                        $ctr++;
                    }
            }

            return $mem_results;
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    //fonction pour échapper les caractères pour les variables post ou get
    //param: valeur
    //retourne la valeur échappée
    function fxEscape($values)
    {
        if (is_array($values))
            $values = array_map(array($this, 'fxEscape'), $values);
        else
        {
            // Stripslashes
            if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                $values = stripslashes($values);

            if ((int)ini_get('magic_quotes_sybase'))
                $values = str_replace("''", "'", $values);

            $values = mysql_real_escape_string($values, $this->con);
        }

        return $values;
    }

    function fxGetLastId() {
        return $this->last_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: add `$GLOBALS['db'] = new clsMysql();` at the top of you main scripts and use `$GLOBALS['db']` in all your functions.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to instantiate the object once and call the query method several times.  It should prevent it from having a connection for each query.

```
$mysql = new clsMysql();

$mysql->fxQuery("select * from something");

$mysql->fxQuery("Another Query");

$mysql->fxQuery("Yet another query...");
```

Answer (score 0):

In an easy way:

```
// on the top of your code
$db = new clsMysql();
```

and then, in your class methods or functions:

```
// class
class abc {

    public function xyz () {
        global $db;            // make it global here

        // use it!
    }
}
```

In another way, more OOP:

```
// main class
class system {

    // variable to the store database object
    public $db;

    // constructor
    public function __constructor() {

        include('mysql.class.php');    // your mysql class file

        $this->db = new clsMysql();
    }

}
```

On the other classes, you can `extend` class `system` then.

```
// sample class
class sample extends system {

    // sample function
    public function sample_method() {

        $this->db->fxQuery('SELECT * FROM table');

}
```

And outside of the class:

```
$app = new system();
$result = $app->db->fxQuery('SELECT 1');
```